# Publish/subscribe Meteor returns a whole Collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, reactjs

I am implementing a publish/subscribe architecture for my Meteor app. I have not removed `autopublish` yet. I use React and `kadira:flow-router` with `kadira:react-layout`. It works fine.

This is my publish code (`/lib/publications.js` though I tried with `/server/publications.js` as well, no change):

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish("games", function() {
        return Games.find({});
    });

    Meteor.publish("game", function(gameId) {
        return Games.find({_id: gameId});
    });

    Meteor.publish("messages", function(gameId) {
        return Messages.find({gameId: gameId}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    });
}
```

Of course if I use it in `/server` I don't add the `if` statement. I subscribe to those publications in the router like this (`/lib/routing.js`):

```
user.route('/game/:id', {
    name: 'game',
    subscriptions: function(params, queryParams) {
        this.register('messages', Meteor.subscribe('messages', params.id));
    },
// ...
});
```

And then I get data in the React component like so (`/client/components/pages/game_page.jsx`):

```
// ...
mixins: [ReactMeteorData],
getMeteorData: function() {
    return {
        messages: Messages.find({}).fetch()
    }
},
// ...
```

Instead of getting all messages that have `gameId` equal to the passed argument I get ALL of the messages from ALL of the games. If I remove the publish/subscribe and just ask for data like this:

```
// ...
mixins: [ReactMeteorData],
getMeteorData: function() {
    return {
        messages: Messages.find({gameId: gameId}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}).fetch()
    }
},
// ...
```

It works perfectly fine. Any idea why? I think I am missing something: either about publish/subscribe itself or about using subscribe in router.

Comment: where is `gameId` set? My suspicion is that it is initially `undefined` and hence meteor subscribes to the whole collection. Since it never unsubscribe from that again, even when later, reactively, the same subscribe runs again, you'll never lose those collections entries.

Comment: It's taken from route. `/game/:id` and passed into subscription as `params.id`. If I `console.log(params.id)` before the `this.register(...)` it properly returns the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autopublish package publishes all data to client (it is like you subscribed to a publication that does `Collection.find({})` on all collections). It means, that your custom publication/subscribtion actually does nothing in your example, and if you query data like this:

```
getMeteorData: function() {
    return {
        messages: Messages.find({}).fetch()
    }
},
```

you will just get all messages, and that's correct behavior.

Anyway, you should always make the explicit query in data query like this:

```
getMeteorData: function() {
    return {
        messages: Messages.find({gameId: gameId}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}).fetch()
    }
},
```

because if you happen to have two different messages subscriptions at the same time (for different purposes, i.e. one subscription for one message with all details and another for different messages with less details/fields), this data query `Messages.find({})` will get you union of the documents subscribed in both subscriptions, and it probably won't be what you would expect.

So, in your case, remove autopublish package, and add this explicit query in data access (`messages: Messages.find({gameId: gameId}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}).fetch()`).

Comment: Yes. After rewriting some portions of the code to be more manageable and more suited for components I must agree that this is the actual answer. `autopublish` needs to be removed and `find({})` is not enough. Full MongoDB query in the `getMeteorData` is required.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to remove the autopublish package because by default it publishes everything in the collection.

From my understanding, every subscription exposes some documents in the collection so if you had you have two subscriptions for the same collection then when you query your collection you will have access to all the documents that two subscriptions expose so it is accumulative.